# Analyze and match all terms in same order

Tags: elasticsearch

**What I want to achieve:**

document: "one two three four"

search strings:

- "one four" (must match)
- "four one" (must not match)

**What I've learned this far:**

For order to be accounted for, the `span_near` query should be used, but this assumes that the terms are already analyzed by the client (all terms must be supplied separately).

To have the search string analyzed, the `phrase_match` query should be used, but it does not take order into account.

It's likely a script should be used (thanks @ChintanShah25), but it seems impossible to analyse the input string inside the script.

**How to achieve both analysis and order requirement?**

Answer (score 4):

There is no straightforward way to achieve this, you could do this with either using `_analyze` endpoint with `span query` or with `script` and `match_phrase`

1) You pass your search string to [_analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-analyze.html) with

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze' -d '
{
  "analyzer" : "my_custom_analyzer",
  "text" : "one four"
}'
```

you will get something like this

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "one",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "four",
         "start_offset": 4,
         "end_offset": 8,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

you then pass the tokens to the [`span query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-span-near-query.html)

```
{
    "span_near" : {
        "clauses" : [
            { "span_term" : { "field" : "token1" } },
            { "span_term" : { "field" : "token2" } }
        ],
        "slop" : 2,
        "in_order" : true,
        "collect_payloads" : false
    }
}
```

2) Another way is to use [advanced scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html#_term_positions_offsets_and_payloads), have a look at the answer of @Andrei Stefan for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634595/preserving-order-of-terms-in-elasticsearch-query), He used `_POSITIONS` with `match_phrase` to get back results with terms in order.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I can tell, @AndreiStefan's solution requires the search string to be processed (tokenised) on the client's side, which is bad news. I guess I am going to have to go with the double-request solution then. Could I write a script that analyses a search string and uses the resulting tokens to do what Andrei Stefan's script does?

Comment: @AndreiStefan's solution is a single request solution, you just pass all terms to script and compare their positions, only downside to that solution is  that `script` can affect performance