# Maintain the order of search for autosuggest in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to implement autocomplete with elasticsearch and I'm unable to do it. I want something like this question here. I tried the suggested answers but in vain. I want to have something like the following :

I have used complete suggester to handle such scenarios .Since order of search is important .

A simple example would be having these documents indexed using standard analyzer:

A :Source B :Destination

```
1. Bus from Alpha to Beta 
2. Morning Bus from Alpha to Beta 
3. Bus Fare from Beta to Alpha
4. Cheapest Bus Fare from Beta via Cita to Alpha
```

I could query for "Alp" and this would return me all documents, including the third and fourth one.I want to retrieve only documents 1 and 2 .If I query "Bet"or "Beta" only documents 3 and documents 4 should return.Slop is not specific to 1 or 2 it can be anything .

Please suggest the index settings properties for this and share the code

What if I wanted to only retrieve the documents which have the terms in this specific order? Can I form a query that would do that for me?

Considering it is possible for phrases by simply quoting the text: "Bus  Alp" ,"Bus Alph"(retrieve 1st and 2nd docs) it feels to me like there should be a way of preserving the order for multiple terms that aren't adjacent.
I have  used complete suggester .But it doesnot seem to solve all the use cases . Please suggest ?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634595/preserving-order-of-terms-in-elasticsearch-query). You can take that approach and remove the optional `slop` factor, and I think this will give you the matching behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving order of terms in ElasticSearch query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634595/preserving-order-of-terms-in-elasticsearch-query)

Comment: @avik:I saw this solution .But there is usage of slop .Slopeness can vary from query to query .How to handle such scenarios?

Comment: Try the `span_near` query _without_ the`slop` setting

Comment: Please share the sample query

Comment: @avik:I have shared the detailed explanation of my requirement .Please share the solution this